# Raspbmc stuck on "updating service management"

Tags: raspbmc, software-installation

I've tried three times now to install Raspbmc on my Pi using the Windows install script to format the SD card (an 8gb SDHC, no USB stick). The initial installation seems to go fine until after it reboots, when it gets stuck on "Updating Service Management". I can SSH in, which walks me through generating locales before giving me a command prompt, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for to determine what is installed. What went wrong?

SSH tells me I'm running Release Candidate 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what various internet tutorials tell you, this is apparently perfectly normal. The tutorials I found show that step passing very rapidly, followed by other, progress-bar-having steps; however, half an hour after seemingly freezing, my box suddenly rebooted again and bam, XBMC fully installed. Maybe it's a glitch of some kind that the other steps weren't shown, but just keep calm and let it run and it'll finish.

Comment: I have seen this too and think it represents a bug.